# Chaque = Tout? Is there a difference?

Tags: grammaire

Can you tell me if chaque and tout are synonymes?

For example:

> Chaque vie est importante/ Toute vie est importante = Every life is important
>
> Toutes les vies sont importantes - All lifes are important

Am I correct?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that you are correct. Still, "chaque" can be translated by "each" in some cases: http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/each

I think sometimes it can be complex to choose the right word (both in English and  French).

Edit: of course, I meant you are correct **in this example**, they are synonyms **in this context**. I assume that you know that *tout* can have multiple use cases, as a noun, an adjective, an adverb, or a pronoun.

Comment: Downvote because not enough information; I think this is misleading or arguably just incorrect.

Comment: I agree it's a simple answer, and it's on purpose, because I think it's almost impossible to find a rule so I only wanted to had the "each" word in the game. In his example, both ("chaque" and "toute") mean exactly the same thing, without more information about the context.

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not synonyms. *Chaque* means *each*. *Tout* and its variants *tous/toute/toutes* mean *all*, *any*, *every*, or *everything*, and while *every* and *any* can be nearly synonymous with *each*, and therefore the two words can be used similarly in some contexts, there are many, many contexts where *tout* has a distinct meaning that is not interchangeable with *chaque*, which only ever means *each*.

**The way you have translated the sentences to English is correct.** I just want to be clear that *tout* and *chaque* are only synonyms in some contexts, not all.

---

Example of *tout*'s non-synonymous usages:

*Tout* is often used to say refer to something's entirety, for example:

> J'ai bu tout le lait.

This means *I drank all the milk*. This is different than saying you drank *each milk*, which would specifically imply there was more than one.

Or another:

> Ça arrive tous les cinq jours.

This means *It happens every five days.* Again, this is a fixed expression for frequency that cannot use *chaque*. Similarly, *tout le temps* is a fixed expression meaning *all the time*....you wouldn't say *each time*, would you? That would be a separate meaning, translated by *chaque fois*.

A last example:

> Il a tout fait.

This means *He did everything,* as if to say that he took care of a job that needed to be done. Again, it makes no sense to use *chaque* here.

Comment: Yes but in a sentence Chaque vie est importante/ Toute vie est importante = Every life is important  is it correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that second sentence is not grammatically correct. *Toute la vie est importante* would mean *All life is important*, but that's a separate meaning from *Each life is important.* You can't write *Toute vie* as you have put there. *Toutes les vies sont importantes* is indeed equivalent to *Chaque vie est importante*, but that's what I mean-- they're synonymous in *this context* but not in general.

Comment: So when you use Tout without an article?

Comment: Your first example doesn't really work. "Milk" should not be plural, as it is a non-count noun.

Comment: It isn't plural....I wrote *tout le lait*

Comment: Toute vérité n'est pas bonne à dire - why it isn't toute LA verite?

Comment: Yes but you cannot write "each milk" as milk is as non-count noun.

Comment: That's my point, that's why they're not synonymous! It would have to be something like *each container of milk* if you used *chaque.* Getting off-topic, sorry if that example implied a misunderstanding.

Comment: @user10544 I don't know....maybe I'm not completely correct! Wait for someone else to weigh in.

Comment: @Aerovistae *Toute vie..* is very correct French and strongly different from *Toute la vie...*

Comment: @user10544 yes, my mistake. I had forgotten that *tout* can also mean *any*, as in *en tout cas* or *de toute façon*. So, yes, I suppose in that context this is close to a synonymous usage with *chaque*. I couldn't tell you the rule for when it's okay to use it that way, if there is such a rule.

Comment: "Toute vie est importante" sounds totally correct, if not even more elevated than "chaque vie est importante". "Toute la vérité n'est pas bonne à dire" means you shouldn't say all the truth about a fact, only a part of it, where "toute vérité n'est pas pas bonne à dire" means you shouldn't say every truth, but only some of them (the ones which will not have bad consequences).

Comment: And it's the same with every concept that can be seen both as a single thing and as multiple things. Example with the milk: "tout le lait" means "all the milk", you are talking about a bottle/glass/whatever of milk ("tu as bu tout le lait !"). But "tout (type de) lait" could mean "every type of milk", probably with the idea of "whole milk and low-fat milk and skim milk and...", like in "tout (type de) lait peut être utilisé en cuisine", which is another way of saying "tous les (types de) laits peuvent [...]", as you could say "toutes les vérités ne sont pas bonnes à dire".

Comment: I share the same understanding as Simon (I'm French).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely they are different !

**Chaque** is usually used when we tend to specify, like saying:

> - Every student must ....
> - Each item has a label.

and so on, so we would use here **chaque**, an example in french:

> - Chaque heure a 60 minutes

so it is a must that every hour to have 60 minutes in it, and every item to have a label ... it means there is no exception no matter what !

However,**tout/toute/tous/toutes** are used when we tend to generalize or describe a frequent habite/event, like saying:

> - We usually go jogging every morning.
> - The sun shines everyday in the sky.

so we would use here **tout** and its siblings.

And if we tried to substitute **tout** in the last two examples with **chaque** ,the meaning will be as specified as following:

> - Each morning we go jogging.
> - Each day the sun shines in the sky.

which will be understood as:

The first example:

There is no morning we don't go jogging no matter what !

The second example:

There is no day you won't see the sun shining in the sky no matter what !

And that is definitely false statement ! because there are some mornings that we maybe won't go jogging, as well there are some days that you won't see the sun shining because of bad weather !

Yes you can sometime substitute one for another, but the meaning will completely be different, as moving from **Specifying <=> Generalizing** and vice versa.

So in your example about the importance of life, when we say:

> - Toute vie est importante.

it sounds to refer to the life in general as a concept or a term. However, saying:

> - Chaque vie est importante.

means that every single life of every being is counted and important in specific.

I hope that I explained it well.

Bonne Chance ;)

Comment: I am not so sure that "Toute vie est importante." implies that there might be some that are not important. It doesn't come to my (french) mind when I hear it.

Comment: @Frank Yeah you are right...actually nor do I feel it that way ... though am not french ... maybe I should modify the answer a bit